# Is it possible to create a reference to block in Eigen3

Tags: eigen3

I want to Create a global matrix

```
G=+---+---+
  | A | B |
  +---+---+
  | C | D |
  +---+---+
```

Is that possible to create a reference to each blocks? So that I can consider each block as a matrix individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is the `Ref` class for that:

```
MatrixXd G(100,100); // global matrix

// reference to sub-blocks:
Ref<MatrixXd> A = G.topLeftCorner(50,50);
Ref<MatrixXd> B = G.topRightCorner(50,50);
Ref<MatrixXd> C = G.bottomLeftCorner(50,50);
Ref<MatrixXd> D = G.bottomRightCorner(50,50);

// Accessing/modifiying the submatrices:
A.setOnes(); 
B.setRandom(); 
C.setIdentity(); 
D = A+B+C;
```

If `G` is `const`, you can make `Ref<const MatrixXd>` to the sub-matrices (these are read-only, of course).